# MySQL: How to add depended records to view

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

***goods***

```
id parent_id name  
1  null      main_part
2  1         add_part1
3  1         add_part2
4  1         add_part3
```

***orders***

```
id good_id  count
1  1        5
```

I want to get a view as :

***orders_view***

```
id  good_id count 
1   1        5 
2   2        5
3   3        5 
4   4        5
```

How to do in MySQL?

Comment: you relation is based on a single level or is a hierarchical structure with nested  leves ??

Comment: Just one level , so only  main_part has descendants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your relation is a single level  you could try joining the subquery for the union with the orders

```
select  t1.id, t1.id good_id,  o.count
from  (
    select id id_master, id 
    from goods 
    where parent_id is null 
    union all 
    select parent_id, id 
    where  parent_id is not  null 
) t 
inner join  orders_view o on o.good_id = t1.id_master
```